# Special Characters ">" not displaying by using UTF-8

Tags: html, css, encoding, utf-8

Here are my codes below:

```
    ul.pathnav a:before{
    content:"\0X3E";
    text-decoration:none;
      }
```

\0x3e is the hex for ">", but it doesn't work.
I tried another special character, it works just fine. For example: in downwards filled triangle, which hex code is \25BC.

Not quite sure what should I add. In the header the code is:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: The correct sequence is `"\003e"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [character escape](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters) syntax in CSS uses just the backslash `\` followed by hexadecimal digits and possibly a whitespace character. An `X` is neither needed nor allowed here. So a proper syntax using an escape would be

```
content: "\3E";
```

On the other hand, there is no need to escape the GREATER THAN character `>` in a CSS string, so you can write just

```
content: ">";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
content:"\0X3E";
```

should be written as

```
content:"\03e";
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3e/index.htm

page for ">" character

Answer (score 1):

Use `\3E` instead of `\0X3E`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nDc3K/

```
p:before {
    content:"\3E";
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

/\

```
<p>Test</p>
```